# AttributeError: type object 'Node' has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

```
class Node():

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None

class LinkedList():

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def push(self, item):
        new_node = Node
        if self.tail is None:
            self.head = self.tail = new_node
        else:
            new_node.prev = self.tail
            self.tail.next = new_node
            self.tail = new_node

    def pop(self):
        if self.tail is not None:
            if self.tail.prev is not None:
                self.tail = self.tail.prev
                self.tail.next = None
            else:
                self.tail = self.head = None
            return self.tail.value
        else:
            return None
```

Can you help me with that?

When i use pop my code gonna crush with that issue:
File "C:\Users\ME\source\repos\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2.py", line 28, in pop
    return self.tail.value
AttributeError: type object 'Node' has no attribute 'value'

Comment: you don't have to use parentheses () on class definition - [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your push function is not creating a node object with any value.

Instead of

```
new_node = Node
```

you need something like:

```
new_node = Node(5)  # pass in some value
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because there is no attribute/class property named value.

Try:

`new_node = Node(1)`

where 1 can be anything and refers to value.

`def __init__(self, value):`